# C# What is the wrong in this reference master page code?

Tags: c#-4.0, coding-style, master-pages

I need to reference a master page to content pages in order to change the css style of the Home page which is referenced to the master page. This is my control which i need to change it, its located on the master page.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="14" border="0" class="navigationButtons">
      <tr>
          <td id="HomeLink" runat="server" align="center"><a href="Home.aspx"><br />Home</a></td>
          <td id="AboutLink" runat="server" align="center"><a href="About.aspx"><br />About us</a></td>
          <td id="ColLink" runat="server" align="center"><a href="Col.aspx"><br />Collections</a></td>
          <td id="RegLink" runat="server" align="center"><a href="Reg.aspx"><br />Register</a></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I need to change the `<td>` style on each content page. I know that I should first reference the master page on the home page for example. But I dont know how to use the `FindControl`. This what I have on my server side.

```
HtmlGenericControl HomeLink = null;
HomeLink = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("HomeLink");
HomeLink.Style.Add["Background-color"] = blue;
```

And of course its not working. Help me please.

Comment: Aren't you missing a runat="server" attribute on the td? Also, you misspelled the id in the findcontrol call.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add runat="server" to your td tags
2. FindControl is not recursive. MSDN says "This method will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx

```
public static Control FindControl(Control control, string id)
{
     if (control.Id == id)
         return control;

     foreach(Control c in control.Controls)
     {
         Control res = FindControl(c, id);
         if (res != null)
              return res;
     }

     return null;
}
```

Comment: can i use this one? WebControl control = (WebControl)FindControl("HomeLink");
        control.Style["Background-Color"] = blue;